# I want to get a value from database and then increment it to use in insert query

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am getting the result from the select query but when i try to increment the value of $slot and then insert in my table 2 rows are added i want to add only 1 row with the incremented value of slot.

Here is my code

```
       try{
 $slot_query="Select max(slot) AS maxslot from mdl_quiz_slots where quizid=$quiid";
     $queryResult=db_query($slot_query);
     foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
 $slot=$row->maxslot;
 $slot++;
 $question_query ="INSERT INTO mdl_quiz_slots ".
   "(slot,quizid,page,requireprevious,questionid,maxmark)".
   "VALUES ".
   "('$slot','$quiid','$page','$requireprevious','$questid','$maxmark')";
    $queryResult=db_query($question_query);

    }
```

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooo. Just use an auto_increment, and there's no need to select anything first.

Comment: can u please write code

Comment: i can not change the db table

Comment: Luckily, that's not our problem. :-)

Comment: what a certified answe.....:)

Comment: Oh gott this code looks so ugly .. And unusable .. And ugly ..

Comment: its code not a painting

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution, but here's something you can play with anyway...

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (i INT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT COALESCE(MAX(i)+1,1) FROM (SELECT 1) x, my_table LIMIT 1;

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

INSERT INTO my_table SELECT COALESCE(MAX(i)+1,1) FROM (SELECT 1) x, my_table LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's enough information here to solve, because I get the feeling you're calling this whole try snippet twice.

Because you're calling a select max query, I expect only one result, but not sure what's happening inside your custom database wrapper class. So you might try to move your insert statement outside the loop

```
try{
 $slot_query="Select max(slot) AS maxslot from mdl_quiz_slots where quizid=$quiid";
 $queryResult=db_query($slot_query);
 foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
   $slot=$row->maxslot;
   $slot++;
 }

$question_query ="
INSERT INTO mdl_quiz_slots 
(slot,quizid,page,requireprevious,questionid,maxmark)
VALUES
('$slot','$quiid','$page','$requireprevious','$questid','$maxmark');
";
$queryResult=db_query($question_query);

}
```

Comment: @UsmanQadeer This isn't helping. If one user was to run an INSERT while another using was running the SELECT, it would be disastrous.

Comment: @Strawberry is it possible to help this situation without altering the database structure?

Comment: @Strawberry can you direct me towards the solution other than the previous one

Comment: @UsmanQadeer I can't offer one that's guaranteed not to run into a race condition. You can look at using transactions and/or running the SELECT as part of the INSERT, but all of these are undesirable hacks, It would be far, far better to remove whatever impediment prohibits you from altering the table - and then let MySQL manage the incrementation, in the way it's designed to do.